# PostgreSQL: Removing object from jsonb[]

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a column named `test_data` that has data looks something like this:

```
{"{\"123\":\"foo\"}","{\"123\":\"foo\"}","{\"123\":\"bar\"}","{\"567\":\"bar\"}"}
```

How would I go about removing only one of `"{\"1234\":\"foo\"}"`?

Also I would like to learn how I could remove `"{\"123\":\"bar\"}"` or `"{\"567\":\"bar\"}"`.

I tried doing

```
UPDATE my_table SET test_data = test_data - '{"123":"foo"}' WHERE id= '1';
```

But, I got the error `ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb[] - unknown`
. What am I doing wrong and is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The `-` operator only works with `jsonb`, not with `json`

Comment: Unrelated, but: you do not need to "escape" double quotes in SQL. `'{\"123\":\"foo\"}'`  should be `'{"123":"foo"}'`

Comment: What exactly is the data type of `test_data`? Is that really `json[]`?  That almost never makes sense. If you want to store an array of JSON documents, use a native JSON array and store that in a `json` column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see, what should I use instead? And I escaped them because they were stored like that. And yes, the data type is indeed `json[]`

Comment: `json[]` may be (and actually is) the cause of many unnecessary problems. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/46015221/1995738

Comment: I made an edit to the question, I am now using `jsonb[]` instead of `json[]` @klin

Comment: `jsonb[]` is just as useless as `json[]`