# Converting jsonb to jsonb array in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I made a mistake designing my schema. I made a column `jsonb` when it should have been `jsonb[]`. Is there a way to cast/convert the data to `jsonb[]`?

The data in the column is a jsonb array of text elements, it just happens to be cast as `jsonb` instead of `jsonb[]`.

Something like:

```
select
  jsonb_to_jsonb_array(jsonb_col)
from
  mytable
```

The larger goal is get the column into a plain pg text array `text[]` such that it can be `unnest`ed. I understand how to do this with `jsonb[]` but am running into issues with `jsonb`.

Comment: `jsonb[]` is probably a bad choice, read [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46015221/1995738)

Comment: I don't think that applies here. I'm storing a flat list of strings/texts.

Comment: So you need `text[]`. Of course, this is your choice. Anyway, you've been warned.

Comment: Did my answer not work for you?

Comment: @BShaps I still need to test this, but it looks great. Thanks for submitting.

Comment: @klin I know I need `text[]`. That's why I mentioned it in the last two sentences of the question.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!

Comment: Ops, I do not know how but I had to overlook the last paragraph, sorry. You can convert `jsonb` to `text[]` with a simple function.

Answer (score 4):

Use the function:

```
create or replace function jsonb_text_array(jsonb)
returns text[] language sql immutable as $$
    select array(select jsonb_array_elements_text($1))
$$;

alter table my_table alter jsonb_col type text[] using jsonb_text_array(jsonb_col)
```

[DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9d4d3449c80e5d03f24d3821ad008b8b)

Answer (score 2):

This syntax works for me

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ALTER COLUMN jsonb_col TYPE JSONB[] USING ARRAY[jsonb_col]::jsonb[];
```