# convert array jsonb to jsonb in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Table: api
column: id serial
Column : jdoc jsonb

```
id = 4, jdoc = [{"a": [2, 3, 4]}]
```

How can I convert jsonb array to jsonb? In another word.
How can I get `id = 4, jdoc = {"a": [2, 3, 4]}`
Similar question: [Converting jsonb to jsonb array in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503972/converting-jsonb-to-jsonb-array-in-postgres)

Comment: I don't quite uderstand your question. A jsonb array is a jsonb. Do you want to extract the first (maybe the only element in your case) element of the array?

Comment: I want to transform from [{"a": [2, 3, 4]}]   to {"a": [2, 3, 4]}

Comment: `select jdoc->0 from api`