# Postgres array of objects error `error: could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"`

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, plpgsql, jsonb

I have been trying to loop over an array of objects in postgres. However, I repeatedly receive the error `error: could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"`. I think it has to do with the value I am passing into the function which looks like so.

```
[
  {
    "number": 1,
    "letter": "a"
  },
  {
    "number": 2,
    "letter": "b"
  }
]
```

The function is as follows. I have made the type ANYARRAY which I assume should do exactly as the name implies. I would not mind a more specific option is available.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "CheckArrayOfObjects" (
  "@arrayOfObjects"           ANYARRAY
)
RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE "e" JSONB;
BEGIN
  FOR "e" IN json_array_elements("@arrayOfObjects")
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Checking Item %', "e";
  END LOOP;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

I have tried a FOREACH as well but it didn't pan out any better. I think the issue lies in the values being passed in so not really sure if modifying the loops will do anything as of now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the argument should be `JSONB` (or `JSON`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "CheckArrayOfObjects" ("@arrayOfObjects" JSONB)
RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE "e" JSONB;
BEGIN
  FOR "e" IN SELECT jsonb_array_elements("@arrayOfObjects")
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Checking Item %', "e";
  END LOOP;
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Example use:

```
SELECT "CheckArrayOfObjects"(
'[
  {
    "number": 1,
    "letter": "a"
  },
  {
    "number": 2,
    "letter": "b"
  }
]')

NOTICE:  Checking Item {"letter": "a", "number": 1}
NOTICE:  Checking Item {"letter": "b", "number": 2}
```

---

UPDATE

> Where do notices get logged with SQL?

It depends on the server configuration parameter [`log_min_messages (enum)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHEN)

> What is the type ANYARRAY for if not for arrays?

It's for Postgres array types, e.g. text[], int[] etc. Json array is not a Postgres array, see [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46015221/1995738)

Comment: Where do notices get logged with SQL? What is the purpose of ANYARRAY if not for arrays?

Comment: @Brandon: a JSON value is something different than a native Postgres array - even if that JSON contains an embedded JSON array.