# ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb[] -> integer

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

```
select id,rules from links where id=2;
 id |                                                                                   rules                                                                                   
----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2 | {"{\"id\": \"61979e81-823b-419b-a577-e2acb34a2f40\", \"url\": \"https://www.wikijob.co.uk/about-us\", \"what\": \"country\", \"matches\": \"GB\", \"percentage\": null}"}
```

I'm trying to get the elements of the jsonb using the operators here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html

Whether I use 'url', or an integer as below, I get a similar result.

```
select id,rules->1 from links where id=2;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb[] -> integer
LINE 1: select id,rules->1 from links where id=2;
                       ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS Postgres version 9.6.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column is an array, you can access the first element using index:

```
select id, rules[1]
from links
where id = 2
```

Be sure to check also [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46015221/1995738)

Use [`jsonb_each()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) in a lateral join to see all rules in separate rows:

```
select id, key, value
from links
cross join jsonb_each(rules[1]) as rule(key, value)
where id = 2
```

You can get a single rule in this way:

```
select id, value as url
from links
cross join jsonb_each(rules[1]) as rule(key, value)
where id = 2 and key = 'url'
```

Use `unnest()` to find an `url` in all elements of the array, e.g.:

```
select id, unnest(rules)->'url' as url
from links
where id = 2;
```

Comment: So, to take it a step further, if I wanted to get a result for every rule in the collection, something like select id, rules[*]->"url" ..., how would I do that?

Comment: Yep, I never would have figured that out, thank you! :)

Comment: One more question, this relies on rules[1]. What if there are multiple rules, as in my schema, it might often be [{url: a}, {url:b}...]; something more like rules[*]?

Comment: @cjm2671 - use `unnest(rules)` to get all jsons in the array.

Comment: Thank you so much, this got me exactly what I needed. I wanted to update and add, I managed to do the last part much more easily, using `select id, unnest(rules)->'url' from links` - I'm not sure if it's the same, but the result appears to be what I was hoping for.

Comment: This simplification is completely correct and produces a better plan, so I replaced the last query in the answer with your solution. Thx for sharing.